# Buck converter efficiency Vs load current:

Tags: power, buck

Can somebody explain how does the efficiency of a buck converter increases with the increasing load current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is no load connected there is no power output but, there will be a little bit of power drawn by the converter to keep it running. This scenario is therefore zero efficient. As output load power increases thus efficiency rises from zero and at some arbitrary point the converter reaches maximum efficiency. At greater loads efficiency decreases due to conduction losses in the switching transistor and inductor (for example).

Basically efficiency = power out / power in and for very low powers being taken by a load the efficiency is going to be very poor.

Comment: Hello Andy, how do we make the module most efficient one? Any tips?

Comment: It's circuit dependent and there are trade-offs so there is no easy answer. A better MOSFET might produce better efficiencies at higher loads but due to switching losses can be worse than a different transistor at lighter loads. A seemingly lower resistance inductor may have problems at at high frequencies whereas an apparently worse inductor may actually result in better efficiency.

Comment: Okay. Also can you tell me the significance of minimum ON time given in the datasheet?

Comment: Data sheet? Which one?

Comment: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3891fa.pdf

Comment: Min on time can restrict the PWM duty cycle limits as PWM frequency rises. At 1MHz a 25ns min on time means you can't have less than 2.5% duty cycle. This might be important because under light load conditions, the output voltage will rise.

Comment: That's why many regulator chips switch to a "pulse skipping" mode under light load -- although this then causes potential problems with extra noise on the output.

Comment: Okay i understand the concept this way. To keep the output voltage at the designed value the minimum ontime  required should be Ton_min. Am i correct? Correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: Output voltage regulation is by altering the duty cycle of the PWM. If the PWM duty cycle is restricted then it doesn't have full regulatory control at extremes of load current and input supply voltage. This can lead to the output voltage rising out of regulation when loads are small. This usually triggers what DT refers to as pulse skipping - the regulator is disabled for an arbitrary period whilst the output voltage decreases to within regulation.