# Rise time and fall time calculation of an integrated switch?

Tags: power, mosfet, buck, switching-regulator

Following the analysis regarding the selection of buck converter for my application ([Buck converter efficiency Vs load current:](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156768/buck-converter-efficiency-vs-load-current)). Now I am trying to estimate the power dissipated in the integrated mosfet switch. In the datasheet [LM5575](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5575.pdf), using the provided parameters how can I calculate the rise-time and fall-time of the switch.
 For the power estimation I have all the parameters ready( Ids, Vsupply, frequency) except the time parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with this graph in the data sheet and note that it is for the demo circuit running at 300kHz. If you are running at a higher frequency losses will likely be greater: -

[image]

The graph above shows plenty of scenarios but to get the chip dissipation you'll need to remove dissipation in the fly-back diode and also take note of what help is given on pages 18 and 19. Page 18 helps you understand the bias power within the chip (mainly in the 7V linear regulator it contains) and there is some good info on the chip dissipation on page 19.

If you still need to calculate rise and fall times in order to work with a formula you have set up then subtracting all the losses the datasheets mention should leave you with switching losses and conduction losses. Conduction losses are directly proportional to the Rds(on) of the mosfet and this is given in the data sheet. This leaves just the switching losses and given the operating frequency, rise and fall times can be inferred.

Comment: But how will I calculate the total power dissipated in the chip?

Comment: Ok ok got it. Its from the above graph.

Comment: Hi Andy, Here again I am confused with the statement he has made in the datasheet. He says Total power losses- diode losses=chip losses, but where is the MOSFET power loss appearing here? Is he neglecting it by saying so? Also how do I calculate the chip losses, if I want to calculate the MOSFET power dissipation?

Comment: Mosfet losses are part of the chip losses